# my datalist is not being shown in html

Tags: html

i am making a datalist which has a textfield as a input type so that user can enter the first alphabet to find the word he is searching for,but only text field is being shown and not the datalist.Here is my code

```
<img class ="top1" src="sing.jpg" height="650" width="700" style="top:100; left:0;"/>
  <div id="inner">
  <input type="text" list="talents" id="cool" value="Talent/Generics">
<datalist id= "Talent">
<select>
    <option value="Dancer"></option>
    <option value="Singer"></option>
    <option value="Pianist"></option>
    <option value="Standup"></option>
    <option value="Violinist"></option>
    <option value="Fautist"></option>
    <option value="Disc Jockey"></option>
    <option value="KeyBoardist"></option>
    <option value="Emcee"></option>
    </select>
</datalist></div>
  </div>
```

Can anybody suggest if there is anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax and not equal "id/list" string "Talent/talents"

```html
<div id="inner">
  <input type="text" list="talent" id="cool" value="Talent/Generics">
  <datalist id="talent">
      <option value="Dancer">
      <option value="Singer">
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You were so close my dude.. Your list="talents" and your input id="Talent" you need to change one of these to make them match..

Good luck man!!

Here is a fiddle confirming it: https://jsfiddle.net/o59tvp5p/

```
  <div id="inner">
  <input type="text" list="talent" id="cool" value="Talent/Generics">
<datalist id="talent">
<select>
    <option value="Dancer"></option>
    <option value="Singer"></option>
    <option value="Pianist"></option>
    <option value="Standup"></option>
    <option value="Violinist"></option>
    <option value="Fautist"></option>
    <option value="Disc Jockey"></option>
    <option value="KeyBoardist"></option>
    <option value="Emcee"></option>
    </select>
</datalist></div>
```

Comment: You have wrong syntax, no `select` inside a `datalist`